# Deploying ASP.NET 2.0 to IIs7

Tags: visual-studio, iis

How to deploy my ASP.NET website to IIS7? I'm using Visual Studio 2005. And I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to take more of a manual approach, but there is a web publish feature built into Visual Studio that should get you going.

Here is some reading you can do on it:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/VSDeploy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's some preliminary steps, a little more manual than some other options, but they are the ones I'm comfortable with:

1. Obtain access to the server where IIS7 is installed.  If you don't have IIS7 installed on a server, install it.  If you are not able to get access to this server, you will need to have the administrator of that server set up IIS7.
2. Create the website in IIS that you want to deploy to, or have the server administrator create an empty website for you to run your website on.
3. Use the 'publish' feature in Visual Studio to build a deployable version of your site.  This is what you will install on IIS7.
4. Copy paste the website over to the server where IIS7 is installed.  You will need to place it in a directory which you can set as the Home Directory for the site.
5. If you have access to the server, and rights to administer IIS7, set the Home Directory of the site to point at the directory where you copied over your files.
6. Enable the website, and you should be good to go!

**NOTES:**
These instructions assume the following:

a) You have some basic knowledge of how to configure IIS7 (or at least access to somebody who does)

b) You have some basic knowledge of how to install IIS7 if it is not installed (or access to somebody who does)

c) You have some basic knowledge on web site publishing from Visual Studio

If you need more instructions on these 3 notes, you may wish to consult the references for IIS7 and Visual Studio.